# AWS, how to prepare for user rush due to Push notification?

Tags: amazon-web-services, push-notification

AWS should be useful for getting more server resources for user rush (for instance due to push notification)

- What are the components (because AWS has so many services) I should look for ?
- would it be possible to increase server capacity dynamically (programmatically) just before we send out all-user push notification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the emphasis on *push notifications* is just for the sake of giving an example for a cause of overloading on EC2 instances; you should first have an [autoscaling group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/AutoScalingGroup.html):

- If the period your load increases is certain and fixed, you can set [scheduled scaling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/schedule_time.html) for that autoscaling group.
- Or, you can watch for metrics such as CPU usage etc. and trigger scaling in & out with events alarmed through CloudWatch. For deeper understanding of the concept, you can check: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-scaling-simple-step.html

Comment: thanks, How about Elasticbeanstalk or ECS ? what are they? they use autoscaling group internally?

Comment: That would probably deserve a new question, but you can think of EBS  as an extra layer for management of instances. Elastic Container Service (ECS), well, a totally different concept than traditional instances and their high availability can be managed by Managed Kubernetes Service; but it is not a cloud-specific concept.

Comment: Would autoscaling be fast enough to respond to huge change as in push notification? (it'll be possible for a push notification to increase traffic more than 10 times in 5 seconds for instance)